# MongoDB búsqueda en elementos anidados

Tags: mongodb

Dada la siguiente colección de Mongo:

```
[{
  "Name": "Group1",
  "Members": [
    {"Name": "Usr17", "email": "usr17@mail.com", "ext": 1700 },
    {"Name": "Usr18", "email": "usr18@mail.com", "ext": 1800 }
  ],
  "Childs": [
    {
      "Name": "Group1.1",
      "Members": [
        {"Name": "Usr11", "email": "usr11@mail.com", "ext": 1100 },
        {"Name": "Usr12", "email": "usr12@mail.com", "ext": 1200 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Group1.2",
      "Members": [
        {"Name": "Usr13", "email": "usr13@mail.com", "ext": 1300 },
        {"Name": "Usr14", "email": "usr14@mail.com", "ext": 1400 }
      ],
      "Childs": [
        {
          "Name": "Group1.2.1",
          "Members": [
            {"Name": "Usr15", "email": "usr15@mail.com", "ext": 1500 },
            {"Name": "Usr16", "email": "usr16@mail.com", "ext": 1600 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "Name": "Group2",
  "Members": [
    {"Name": "Usr27", "email": "usr27@mail.com", "ext": 2700 },
    {"Name": "Usr28", "email": "usr28@mail.com", "ext": 2800 }
  ],
  "Childs": [
    {
      "Name": "Group2.1",
      "Members": [
        {"Name": "Usr21", "email": "usr21@mail.com", "ext": 2100 },
        {"Name": "Usr22", "email": "usr22@mail.com", "ext": 2200 }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Group2.2",
      "Members": [
        {"Name": "Usr23", "email": "usr23@mail.com", "ext": 2300 },
        {"Name": "Usr24", "email": "usr24@mail.com", "ext": 2400 }
      ],
      "Childs": [
        {
          "Name": "Group2.2.1",
          "Members": [
            {"Name": "Usr25", "email": "usr25@mail.com", "ext": 2500 },
            {"Name": "Usr26", "email": "usr26@mail.com", "ext": 2600 }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

¿cómo puedo realizar una búsqueda en profundidad que retorne el objeto correspondiente a un usuario en particular, sin importar en que nivel anidado se pueda localizar?, por ejemplo encontrar al usuario con la extensión 2500, el cual está en el grupo 2.2.1 (en profundidad).

He intentado realizar búsquedas como `{"Members.ext":2500}` y no arrojan ningún resultado, no obstante al buscar `{"Members.ext":1700}` obtengo como respuesta todo el objeto correspondiente al grupo 1 con todos los elementos anidados.

Agregar parámetros delimitadores de campos a la búsqueda solo hace que la consulta regrese un objeto vacío.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb es una base de datos no relacional que almacena sus datos similares a Json, se podría decir que sus documentos representan a un árbol en sí, "es por esto que su logo es una hoja". Si le dices que busque como tú comentaste en tu pregunta:

```
db.collection.find({
  "Members.ext": 1700
})
```

Le dices a mongo que busque en todo el documento el campo los campos `ext` con el valor `1700` del campo `Members`  y mongo te lo va a encontrar ya que ese valor existe en el mismo nivel. Si le dices que busque:

```
db.collection.find({
      "Members.ext": 2500
    })
```

Te va a dar error ya que no encuentra en ese nivel ese campo. Para que te arroje algún  resultado podrías usar esta consulta:

```
db.collection.find({
  "Childs": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "Childs": {
        $elemMatch: {
          "Members.ext": 2500
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Esto si, te lo va a encontrar y a mostrar. Pero el problema es que te arroja mucho dato basura, y como no tengo idea de como quieres que te devuelva la salida muy poco te puedo ayudar. Aún así, mejor que leas la documentación de Mongodb [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) , donde sale la función aggregate que permite procesar los datos como uno quiere.

Comment: Buen aporte, pero dices: *Te va a dar error ya que no encuentra en ese nivel ese campo*. Lo cierto es que no arrojará error, simplemente devolverá un valor `null`. Ya que no encontrará nada. Ojo con confundir un error con una búsqueda que no produce resultados, son cosas diferentes. Saludos

Comment: Mi error, buena acotación. Lo comenté respondiendo con respecto pregunta y no aclaré ese punto.